# nginx replace a plus for a dash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, substitution

I am very new to nginx but i have been tasked with doing some rewrite rules to cover a new URI structure as part of a website migration. I have browsed this site and i see that there is a solution that I'm not sure will work for us.

Basically i take a URL like
abc.com/l/hello+there 
and replace it with
abc.com/address/hello-there

So the replacement of the "/l/" to "/address" is easy, but the replacement of the "+" to "-" seems very tricky as I cant seem to manipulate the variable $2, where it sits.

Has anyone any suggestions ? It was suggested that i just redirect it to a javascript back end as it would be much easier to handle there. If there was a solution where the "+" to "-" replacement could happen in the server block, and then passed to the location block for the processing of the "/l/" to "/address".

Any suggestions would be greatly accepted.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: If you're happy to use openresty then you could do this fairly easily in the access_by_lua block.

Comment: HI .. Thanks for the response. I haven't heard of Lua actually, but after a quick google, it reads as if its more powerful. How would something like that look ?

Comment: Actually, an important thing to note, the URI will not always be the same structure, it may be something like /hello+there+everyone, for example. Basically the URI doesn't have a predefined structure, only that it will contain a variable amount of "+".